# How to enter data in WinEdit which is non editable

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I want to enter data in `WinEdit` field which is non editable manually.

Is there any option we have like DOM for `WebEdit`? (i.e. `Object.innertext="usertext"`)

Please help me out in this. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `WinEdit.Set "your text"`?

Comment: You can try to access the `.Object` properties to enable the field (I *think* it is something like `WebEdit().Object.readOnly = False` but I'm not sure, you should inspect it or check it at the DOM), then edit, and after that remember to disable it again.

Comment: @VictorMoraes Standard Windows objects in UFT (such as `WinEdit`) don't support `.Object`.

Comment: @Motti sorry about that. It's been a while since the last time I got access to UFT, so I'm unable to test it out